# ¿Porque cuando quiero integrar el metodo de pago de paypal o de donacion me sale error en la app de android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Lo que quiero es poner un botón de donativos en mi app de android pero al dar clic en el radio button que debe de realizar la acción me saca de la app y no me manda ningún error

```
  final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
                      final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AYQ255Q-RypOwx9EECGpUL23s8s-mswtxV8P93wqnynrb3euuljmoNjqxDPZbYDzLzhuzGgR2hARVFe9";
                      final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;

                    PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
                            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
                            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
                            .merchantName("CocinApp");

                    PayPalPayment thingToBuy;

                    thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("50"), "USD",
                            "pelicula", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PaymentActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
```

El codigo de arriba es el que en teoría se encarga de realizar todo el proceso, ya esta incluido el sdk de paypal por lo que no sale errores de sintaxis solo de resultado pero no me indica cual.

Comment: Que error, revisaste el LogCat?

Comment: OJO, si pones un botón de donación dentro de la App de Android, puede que Google suspenda tu App, así de sencillo. Si esto no ha cambiado (debes revisar las normas actuales) el único canal por el que puedes recibir dinero es el canal de Google (Google Play si la App es de pago, o Google Ads). No se te permiten botones de PayPal, aunque la App sea gratuita. Creo que el único caso permitido es si tienes una organización sin fines de lucro y aportas documentación. [Lee esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057032/5587982) e investiga, porque te puedes encontrar con que suspenden tu App.